# Is there any way to display a raw image in python?

Tags: python

I want to display the raw image in RGB565-Big Endian or gray 16 bit Big-Endian. The result of this code is little-Endian

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
from struct import *



fd = open('path', 'rb')
rows = 360
cols = 640
f = np.fromfile(fd, dtype=np.int16,count=rows*cols)
im = f.reshape((rows, cols)) #notice row, column format
fd.close()

print(fd)

cv2.imshow('', im)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what is the problem? are you getting an error?

Comment: I dont get an error. Unfortunately I can only display the picture in little endian but i want it in big endian.

Comment: can you include an example image?

Answer (score 0):

from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html

replace your dtype in line 11 with:

```
dtype='>i2'
```

`>` stands for big endian

`i` stands for integer

`2` stands for 2 bytes

Comment: the result is the same